# Rotation matrix construction

Tags: matrices, transformation, rotations

I'm reading a book on how to construct transformation matrices and I'm stuck in a certain point.

From the book:

[image: img]

Now here's the figure that I don't understand:

[image: figure 3.3]

How come the opposite edge in the right triangle is `|Q|sin(theta)`?
When doing sine in that triangle I get `opposite edge = |P'|sin(theta)`.

I don't understand the adjacent edge calculation as well, and equation (3.12) doesn't make sense to me as well.

Comment: $P, P' \text{ and } Q$ all have the same length, whoever wrote the book is falling short of perfection here, but it is correct. I think they probably intended to make the dotted lines labelled as vectors rather than just magnitudes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $Q$ is formed by rotating the vector $P$ through 90 degrees. Therefore $P$ and $Q$ have the same length.

The diagram is drawn very badly, in my opinion.

Comment: What about P'? How can you prove it has the same length of P?

Comment: Also how did he get the final equation?

Comment: He says that $P'$ is formed by rotating $P$ by an angle $\theta$. So, again, $P'$ has the same length as $P$.

Answer (score 0):

The author is trying to emphasize the point of view that the rotated vector $\mathbf P'$ is a linear combination of $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf Q$. By construction, $\|\mathbf P\|=\|\mathbf Q\|$, so of course $\|\mathbf P\|\sin\theta=\|\mathbf Q\|\sin\theta$.