# Adding $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ of Perpendicular Vectors

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

In order to derive 3D rotation formula known as Rodriguez formula, I am trying to figure out a vector calculation given in the [book](http://szeliski.org/Book/) by Szeliski pg. 38, where for the figure given below

[image]

The context here is rotation: $u$ is the rotated form of $v$ around the axis $\hat{n}$ after a rotation of $\theta$ degrees. The magnitude of $u$ and $v$ would be the same. $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector and is normal to the plane shown above.

After some derivations for $v_\perp$ and $v_x$ (which I understand) the author uses

$$u_\perp = \cos \theta v_\perp + \sin \theta v_x$$

where $v_x$ is simply $v_\perp$ rotated 90 degrees. The formula above is the part I do not understand - I guess I missing an identity for triangles.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: This can be shown only if some additional relation between $u$ and $v$ is known to be true. The equation you have written down implies, for example, a relation for $|u_\perp|$ in terms of $v_\perp$ and $v_x$. Maybe you should tell a bit more about the original problem.

Comment: You should find everything you need in these Wikipedia articles : [Rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) and [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). Notice that you are really interested in the vector expression of a **plane** rotation. Notice also that the coordinates of $v_x$ depend trivially on the coordinates of $v_{\perp}$.

Comment: So I can rotate $v_\perp$ by creating the appropiate rotation matrix $R$ and calculating $u_\perp = R \cdot v_\perp$. How can I include $v_x$ in this? Why would I need to?

Comment: You don't need to, but it may be a bit simpler. To make $v_x$ appear, develop the matrix product, and put apart the $\cos \theta$ coefficients (you will get $v_\perp$), and the $\sin\theta$ ones (show it's $v_x$).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotation matrix construction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579111/rotation-matrix-construction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Jean-Claude Arbaut's suggestion,

$$ 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
v_\perp^1 \\
v_\perp^2
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
v_\perp^1 \cos \theta  - v_\perp^2 \sin \theta \\
v_\perp^2 \cos \theta  + v_\perp^1 \sin \theta  
\end{array}\right]
$$

$$ =
\cos \theta
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
v_\perp^1  \\
v_\perp^2   
\end{array}\right] 
+ 
\sin \theta
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
 - v_\perp^2  \\
 + v_\perp^1  
\end{array}\right] 
$$

Since $v_x$ is 90 degree rotated form of $v_\perp$, and that rotation looks like this,

$$ 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
v_\perp^1 \\
v_\perp^2
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-v_\perp^2 \\
v_\perp^1
\end{array}\right]
$$

RHS looks like the term after $\sin \theta$, so we can substitute $v_x$ there, then

$$ = \cos \theta v_\perp + \sin \theta v_x $$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $v_x$ has been obtained from $v_\perp$ by rotation through $\pi/2$ in the direction from $v_1$ toward $u_\perp.$ If (as it is here) the vectors $v_\perp, v_x$ have the same length and are orthogonal, then polar coordinates may be set up in their plane by the usual formula $r(v_1 \cos t, v_\perp \sin t)$ where $t$ (the polar angle) is being measured from $v_1$ towards $v_\perp.$

Here $r$ is just a scale factor to enable representing all points (except the origin) in that polar form. For your diagram, you can take $r=1$ in this, since you already know the length of $u_\perp$ is the same as the equal lengths of $v_\perp,v_x.$ Finally the angle $t$ in the above polar form is taken to be called $\theta$ to match the diagram.

Comment: Note since the $v_1,v_\perp$ are vectors, the polar form is also expressible as $\cos t v_1 + \sin t v_\perp,$ [Actually my version is bad format in a way, since one doesn't typically put vectors in as coordinates of an ordered pair for the Cartesian form.]